# Rewriting request before sending to mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am running Tomcat on Ubuntu 12.10 and have a webapp installed. It works fine when accessed using Tomcat (localhost:8080/webappname). Requests to a servlet using this method appear in the Tomcat access log as /webappname/servlet/servletname. However, I would prefer to host the static http files using apache httpd instead. Thus, I installed and configured mod_jk.

The problem is that requests from the httpd server show up in the Tomcat log /servlet/servletname, missing the webapp name in front, and thus returning 404.

I tried adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/servlet/(.*)& /webappname/servlet/$1 [PT]
```

to apache's virtual host config, but this did not work. I don't know if rewrites are passed on to mod_jk.

What is the best way to tackle this problem? Should the request be rewritten in the httpd server, or is there a way to tell Tomcat to forward the request to a specific webapp?

Edit:

These lines are in the virtual host config:

```
JkMount /servlet/ ajp13
JkMount /servlet/* ajp13
```

This is the config file for mod_jk:

```
    <IfModule jk_module>
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/jk_workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
JkWatchdogInterval 60
<Location /jk-status>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
<Location /jk-manager>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Here is the workers properties file:

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
max_packet_size=65536
```

Comment: You need to provide the mod_jk configuration you are using.

Comment: Edited post to provide config info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
JkMount /webappname/servlet/ ajp13
JkMount /webappname/servlet/* ajp13
```

Comment: Thanks -- this seems to work, and Tomcat is receiving the requests. I now have the problem that requests sent this way are provoking Serialization Exceptions from GWT rpc, but that is outside the scope of this question. Thanks again.